# many routing for same controller action

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I use symphony § and I manage my routes in `routing.yml` function, 
How can I use mutliples routes for same controller function. I know I can do it with annotation but I don't manage my routes in annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple routes for the same controller in `routing.yml` as in annotations.

If there are multiples routes matching the url, the firt one win, as explained [in the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/requirements.html).